Indy IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge/TIdCustomHTTPServer threads keep on increasing
I have an TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge class which descends from TIdCustomHTTPServer and overrides the DoCommandGet() method. Below is the basic code structure.
procedure TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.DoCommandGet(AThread: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  LRequest: TIdHTTPAppRequest;
  LResponse: TIdHTTPAppResponse;
begin
  LRequest := TIdHTTPAppRequest.Create(AThread, ARequestInfo, AResponseInfo);
  try
    LResponse := TIdHTTPAppResponse.Create(AThread, LRequest, ARequestInfo, AResponseInfo);
    try
      // WebBroker will free it and we cannot change this behaviour
      AResponseInfo.FreeContentStream := False;

      try
        if TWebDispatcherAccess(FWebModule).DispatchAction(LRequest, LResponse) then
        begin
          if not LResponse.Sent then
          begin
            LResponse.SendResponse;
          end;
        end;
    finally FreeAndNil(LResponse); end;
  finally FreeAndNil(LRequest); end;
end;

I noticed that the thread count of the process keeps slowly increasing and even reached around above 1500 threads. Only this object is creating threads. I am not sure why it keeps increasing over time.
What might cause the threads to stay and not get released? I did set KeepAlive to true to save on the SSL handshake costs.
I have tried logging all requests and responses and do not see any error that might cause this.
I also did not find any long running processes that are stuck in an infinite loop. The thread count does not justify the activity going on. Even when there is no more activity, the thread count does not decrease.
I'm already using the latest Indy v10.6.3.3.

The code you showed is not what TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.DoCommandGet() actually looks like in the latest version of Indy. In any case, did you check to see if you are getting OnDisconnect events from the server?  The threads should be terminating if the clients are disconnecting, but with KeepAlive=true it may take some time for them to disconnect.

Thank you for the reply @RemyLebeau. This unit was customized from before and upon checking against the latest version, it is more or less the same. But will try to update this. Will also add logging on the tcp connections and disconnections.
Is there like a keepalive timeout? And is it possible for threads to stay alive indefinitely even if the client disconnects?

@RemyLebeau In the latest (and even on older) version, LWebModule variable is instantiated on every call which we optimized to only instantiate once as there are very many webactions on the module and loading on every call takes some time. Is this optimization ok to do?  Comparing our code against the latest version, I cannot find anything that might explain the threads not terminating.

"Is there like a keepalive timeout?" - not currently, but there is work on that that hasn't been checked into the master code yet. But you can set a ReadTimeout to get a similar effect. "is it possible for threads to stay alive indefinitely even if the client disconnects?" - not by default, no. That would imply the threads are not being terminated properly, or the threads are deadlocking. If you were using the pooling thread scheduler, then threads could stay running, but that is not the default.

@RemyLebeau I catch all exceptions and log them on all webactions and also return the appropriate error response codes and message. I did not see any EIdException classes or its descendants raised. My initial thought was that I  need to re-raise these exceptions. But there aren't any in our logs. Thanks for your inputs. Will dig into this deeper.

@RemyLebeau Will calling AContext.Binding.SetKeepAliveValues in the OnConnect event help?
About the ReadTimeout. can I set this during the OnConnect event like AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadTimeout := 300000;
What is the difference of ReadTimeout vs using TCP Keepalive?

"Will calling SetKeepAliveValues help?" - it won't hurt, at least. "can I set ReadTimeout during the OnConnect event" - yes. Or any other time you want. "What is the difference of ReadTimeout vs using TCP Keepalive?" - ReadTimeout is high level implemented by Indy, TCP keepalive is vs low level implemented by the OS. In any case, you are assuming the problem is the TCP connection not being closed properly, vs a thread not being terminated properly after a closure. Two different issues, and the root issue hasn't been diagnosed one way or the other yet.
